# Integrating Struts2 Sitemesh DWR

Tags: struts2, dwr, sitemesh

I'm attempting to integrate Struts2 ver 2.5.2, DWR ver 2.0,5, and Sitemesh ver 2.5. My DWR is (almost) already work fine. I can open [CONTEXT]/dwr/engine.js and util.js, and also [CONTEXT]/dwr/interface/Arithmetic.js.

The problem is, when I open index.jsp which contains dwr call, the dwr js variable is not defined as well the Arithmetic variable.

The index.jsp itself already decorated from the Sitemesh filter.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value> true </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>crossDomainSessionSecurity</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener- class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.listener.StrutsListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

decorators.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
<excludes>
    <pattern>/dwr/*</pattern>
</excludes>
<decorator name="basic-theme" page="basic-theme.jsp">
    <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>
</decorators>
```

dwr.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE dwr PUBLIC
"-//GetAhead Limited//DTD Direct Web Remoting 2.0//EN"
"http://directwebremoting.org/schema/dwr20.dtd">
<dwr>
<allow>
    <create creator="new" javascript="HelloAjaxService">
        <param name="class"   value="com.test.struts.ajax.HelloAjaxService" />
    </create>
 </allow>
</dwr>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/strutsSitemesh/dwr/engine.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/strutsSitemesh/dwr/util.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/strutsSitemesh/dwr/interface /HelloAjaxService.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div
    style="background-color: #ffeaa7; font-weight: bold; width: 300px;"
    id="divResponse">
    <s:form action="hello" method="post">
        <s:textfield id="name" name="name" label="Name" size="20"
            onkeypress="sayHello()" />
        <s:textfield name="age" label="Age" size="20" />
        <s:submit name="submit" label="Submit" align="center" />
    </s:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sayHello() {
        console.log(dwr.util.getValue("name"));
            HelloAjaxService.sayHelloAjax(function(data) {
                dwr.util.setValue("divResponse", data);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I commented **filter-mapping sitemesh** ---- the DWR call will work just fine. So I assume, the request will filtered by SitemeshFilter, and strangely it will not go to DWR filter. I tried to search about how to arrange filter in sequence, but nothing comes up. Any help appreciated. Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved it by moving dwr js declaration to the body tag of index.jsp. It happened because in my decorators.jsp, I only put `<decorator:body>`, and because of that, the `<head>` tag in decorators.jsp take precedence of the actual .jsp file(In this case, index.jsp).